# Verification of the proof that the derivative of 1/x exists using the definition.

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove that the derivative of 1/x exists. Is my proof correct? Please help me!

***Proof.***

According to the definition of the derivative.

[image]

It is necessary to analyze two cases:

***Case numer 1: x is not equal to 0.***

For this case f(x), f(a), x, and a exist because 1/x is a continuous function everywhere except when x=0 because x is a polynomial and 1/x is undefined only when the denominator is equal to 0, what happens only when x=0.

***Therefore the derivative exists when x is not equal to 0.***

***Case numer 2: x is equal to 0.***

Let analyze the graph of 1/x.

[image: Plot of 1/x]

1/x is discontinuous at x=0 because the left limit and right limit of 1/x is not the same.

***As continuity is a necessary condition for differentiability, 1/x is not differentiable at x=0. Q.E.D.***

Comment: You've demonstrated that $f$ is continuous for $x\neq 0$; however, continuous does not imply differentiable.  To show that it is differentiable, you need to show that the limit that defines the derivative exists at all points $x\neq 0$.

Comment: Hint: Analyze $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{a}}{x-a}$ and verify that the limit is indeed $\frac{-1}{x^2}$ (for $x\neq 0$).

Comment: @NickPeterson Thank you for your help! I have a question. As f(x), f(a), x and a exist, then f(x)-f(a) and x-a exist. Then the limit and the derivative exist, or not?

Comment: @JustinBenfield Thank you for your help and you hint! May you read my last comment and answer that question?

Comment: You get $0/0$ when you attempt to directly evaluate the limit, this is what is known as an *indeterminant form*. This does not reveal whether or not the limit is actually defined (you need a *determinant form*) (ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form).

Comment: @JustinBenfield Fantastic explanation! Thank you so much!

Comment: Even worse -- $f$ is not even *defined* at $0$, so the difference quotient $\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$ is meaningless no matter what $x$ is

Comment: @MPW Thank you for your help. However, the case when x=0 is under case number 2, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. But I'm just pointing out that the reasoning there is not quite right. Technically, it is not true that $f$ is discontinuous at $x=0$. $f$ is neither continuous nor discontinuous there, because it isn't defined there. Continuity or discontinuity is only meaningful at points in the domain of the function. To your credit, your observation *does* show that there is no way to extend the domain to include $x=0$ in such a way that the extension is continuous at $0$. So there is no hope of extending $f$ so that it becomes differentiable at $0$.

Comment: @MPW Your ideas are brilliant! I appreciate them a lot! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the case $a \neq 0$ we have that

$$ \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a} = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{\frac 1 x - \frac 1 a}{x-a} = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{\frac{a - x}{ax}}{x-a} = \lim_{x \to a} -\frac{1}{ax} = -\frac{1}{a^2}.$$

If $a = 0$ then $f$ is not continuos and hence not differentiable.

I hope it helps you :)

Comment: Should be $-1/a^2$ at the end, since $x\rightarrow a$, not other way around.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Was a typo :)

Comment: @Yaddle Thank you so much! Very nice...